# Unexpected result of std::is_invocable over a template type

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I have an `if constexpr` checking that a type is equality-comparable with itself. I use `std::is_invocable_v<std::equal_to<>, T, T>`.

However, when `T` is a vector of incomparable structs, the snippet falsely returns True. Is there a deep reason for it or is it a compiler bug?

Minimal example follows.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TNonComparable{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_invocable_v<std::equal_to<>, TNonComparable, TNonComparable> << "\n";
    // 0

    std::cout << std::is_invocable_v<
            std::equal_to<>,
            std::vector<TNonComparable>,
            std::vector<TNonComparable>
        > << "\n";
    // 1

    std::vector<TNonComparable> vec;
    // vec == vec;
    // (expected) compilation error
}
```

I checked the output at Godbolt's, it is the same for all recent versions of g++ and clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is correct behavior.

In the first `std::is_invokable_v` checks for the presence of the `operator==` in the `TNonComparable` type. It is not present - so the result is 0.

In the second case `std::is_invokable_v` checks for the equality operator of the `std::vector`, which is present and may be invoked. But if do try to invoke it, it won't be able to compile because the `TNonComparable` type doesn't have `operator==`. But before you don't try to use it, it won't generate an error.

Maybe, in second case you should check for value_type of the std::vector:

```
std::cout << std::is_invocable_v<
        std::equal_to<>,
        std::vector<TNonComparable>::value_type,
        std::vector<TNonComparable>::value_type
    > << "\n";
// 0
```

Comment: Well, that sounds reasonable, thanks. Do you have any idea on how to perform the deep check automatically? I can probably write the recursive checker that detects ::value_type and similar and recursively checks their comparability, but it will fail on user-defined compound objects.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov: "*Do you have any idea on how to perform the deep check automatically?*" You can't *make* something use SFINAE that doesn't use SFINAE. If `vector`'s equality operator isn't SFINAE friendly, then your test about `vector`'s equality operator won't be SFINAE friendly either. It's best to just accept the limitations of the code you're given and forward those limitations to the user.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's very important to [look at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) what `std::is_invocable` does:

> Determines whether `Fn` can be invoked with the arguments `ArgTypes...`.
> Formally, determines whether `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` **is well formed when treated as an unevaluated
> operand, where `INVOKE` is the operation defined in `Callable`**.

<sub>Emphasis mine.</sub>

The important part to note here is that `std::equal_to<>` used inside `std::is_invocable` will never be evaluated because it's a unevaluated operand. This means that it only checks if `operator==` exists at all, which it does for `std::vector<>`, not if it would compile in an evaluated context.

Answer (score 1):

Had some time and I've wrote workaround tool

```cpp
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T, typename=void>
    struct has_value_type : std::false_type {};

    template<typename T>
    struct has_value_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>> : std::true_type {};

    template<typename T, typename=void>
    struct is_pair : std::false_type {};

    template<typename T, typename U>
    struct is_pair<std::pair<T, U>, void> : std::true_type {};

    template<typename T, typename=void>
    struct is_tuple : std::false_type {};

    template<typename ...Args>
    struct is_tuple<std::tuple<Args...>, void> : std::true_type {};
}

template<typename T, typename=void>
struct has_euqual_operator : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_euqual_operator<
        T, 
        std::void_t<
            std::enable_if_t<
                !detail::is_pair<T>::value 
                && !detail::has_value_type<T>::value 
                && !detail::is_tuple<T>::value>,
            decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>())
        >
    > : std::true_type 
{};

template<typename T>
struct has_euqual_operator<
        T, 
        std::enable_if_t<has_euqual_operator<typename T::value_type>::value>
    > : std::true_type 
{};

template<typename T>
struct has_euqual_operator<
        T, 
        std::enable_if_t<has_euqual_operator<typename T::first_type>::value
            && has_euqual_operator<typename T::second_type>::value
        >
    > : std::true_type 
{};

template<typename ...Args>
struct has_euqual_operator<
        std::tuple<Args...>, 
        std::enable_if_t<(... && has_euqual_operator<Args>::value)>
    > : std::true_type 
{};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rcejhx